# Using @ClusteringColumn and @Index in achilles cassandra on same column

Tags: java, orm, cassandra

I need to use same column as clustering column and secondary index. But achilles compilation fails.

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(table="users")
public class Users{
    @PartitionKey
    @Column
    private String userID;

    @Index(name = "fname")
    @ClusteringColumn
    @Column
    private String fname;
}
```

But compiler throws error as below:

```
[ERROR] /D:/Work/Codebase/itam-common/schema/target/generated-sources/annotations/info/archinnov/achilles/generated/dsl/Users_SelectIndex.java:[466,44] method fname() is already defined in class info.archinnov.achilles.generated.dsl.Users_SelectIndex.E
```

I am using achilles-core: 5.3.1 and cassandra-driver-core:3.3.0

Comment: What version of lombok are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving different name for your `@Column` and `@Index` annotation:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(table="users")
public class Users{
    ...
    @Index(name = "fname_idx")
    @ClusteringColumn
    @Column(name = "fname")
    private String fname;
    ...
}
```

Comment: No its doesn't work that way. I confirmed with achilles team, as of now they dont support it, You may need to have a duplicate column in that case, one with ClusteringColumn and one with Index.
Did you try your example compiling???